# how to configure redmine to show the latest git commits

Tags: git, ssh, redmine

hey guys i am trying to configure on redmine project with git and i have successfully cloned a redmine project using smartgit, the problem is that now when i make changes to the project that i have cloned locally , and push them to redmine, there is no update shown in redmine , so i came across the [this](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/07/configuring-git-repository-with-redmine/) article that talks about configuring redmine to track all the changes made to the project.

The above article says that i need to navigate to the project and then go to :

```
Settings > repository
```

and then make the configuration , the problem is i see no such option in my redmine directory, so how do i configure redmine now. The article i read dates back to 2009 and probably things have changed since then , i have surfed the net alot and i can't see any other article that discusses this issue , can somebody help me here.

I have been using git for a while now . but i am relatively new to Redmine.

Thankk you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Easily_integrate_a_%28SSH_secured%29_GIT_repository_into_redmine) some time ago on redmine.org. I think the 2nd chapter should help you:

> Step 2: Introduce the repository to redmine
>
> Inside redmine we open the `administration > project -> repositories` dialog. You can access this dialog also via `project -> settings -> repositories`. There we add a new repository
>
> - Type: GIT
> - Main-repository: check this if the cloned repository is you main repository, if not leave it unchecked.
> - Name (redmine intern): I suggest to choose the same name as the repository, e.g. `my_repo`
> - Path: Absolute path of the repository, e.g. `/var/lib/redmine/repos/my_repo`
>
> Now redmine knows the repository. If you open the `repository`-tab inside your project you will see the repository tree, last commits and so on.

If you still now see the repository page please check if you have installed redmine right and if you have the correct admin rights inside redmine.